# cannot add or update a parent row using netbeans

Tags: java

I had a problem with my code when it came to create `seance` where there is a foreign key for another table `teacher`, this error appears:

> a foreign key constraint fails (`classroommanag`.`seance`, CONSTRAINT `seance_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_teacher`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`))

I tried many solution but it didn't work.
There is my code :

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classroommanag";
String login ="root";
String psswd ="";
String group= jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
int teacher=0;

try {
     Timestamp currentdate = new Timestamp((new java.util.Date().getTime()));
     jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, psswd);
     Statement st=cn.createStatement();
     Statement stat=cn.createStatement();
     String req = " SELECT id FROM goupe WHERE groupname = '"+group+"';";
     ResultSet com = st.executeQuery(req);

     while(com.next()) {
         idgroup = com.getInt("id");}
         String re = " SELECT id FROM teacher WHERE name = '"+AuthentServer.getname()+"' and password='"+AuthentServer.getpass()+"';";
         ResultSet con= stat.executeQuery(re);
         id = con.getInt("id");
         String ti = " INSERT INTO seance (`temp`,`id_group`,`id_module`,`id_teacher`)VALUES('"+currentdate+"','"+idgroup+"','"+idgroup+"','"+id+"')";
         st.execute(ti);
         String sql = " SELECT name,etat FROM student WHERE id_goupe='"+idgroup+"';";
         ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sql);

         while (rs.next()) {
             String nom=rs.getString("name");
             int etat=rs.getInt("etat");

             if(etat==1) {
                 jComboBox1.addItem(nom+"   connected");
                 currentdate=new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                 String  date=currentdate.toString().substring(0,10);
                 String nomDossier="C:/wamp/www/cmsEnseignant/Travaux/"+group+"/"+nom+"/"+date;
                 File dir = new File (nomDossier);
                 if(!dir.isDirectory()) {
                     dir.mkdirs();
                 }
             }
             else {
                 jComboBox1.addItem(nom+"   not connected");
                 currentdate=new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
                 String  date=currentdate.toString().substring(0,10);
                 String nomDossier="C:/wamp/www/cmsEnseignant/Travaux/"+group+"/"+nom+"/"+date;
                 File dir = new File (nomDossier);
                 if(!dir.isDirectory()) {
                     dir.mkdirs();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WorkSpace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(WorkSpace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i did put the image of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`a foreign key constraint fails`** usually occurs when you try to insert a data to a child table which is not present in the parent table. As in your `seance` table, the `id_teacher` is the foreign key which references the `id` from `teacher` table, then the id you are inserting as `id_teacher` to `seance` table must be present in the `teacher` table as primary key `id`.

**Update:**

In your code, after you executed the query using `ResultSet con= stat.executeQuery(re);`, you are directly fetching values using `id = con.getInt("id");`

But if you see the official documentation for [Resultset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), there is written:

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of
>   data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The
>   next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns
>   false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be
>   used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

So, this one line should solve your problem. As you haven't used any `next()` method, the cursor is positioned before the first row which is an invalid data for your foreign key. That's why you were getting error.

To solve this, either you have to use while loop with `con.next()` to iterate through all the rows if your query should return multiple rows or you may use 
`con.next()`  once if it should return only one row of data.

Comment: Yes I did that but it doesn't work and there is the structure of the 'teacher' table :

Comment: Codes with images are hard to debug. Can you please post the full code here or somewhere else and provide the link?

Comment: @TimaFatimz I've updated the answer, look at it...hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: thank you i thought that to but after trying it still get the same error don't know why